# How to call Creator Method's

Tags: c#, winforms, syntax

If we have a Class

```
public class A
{
    public void resetValues()
    {
        //DoSomething
    }

    B b = new B();
}
public class B
{
    public B()
    {

    }

    void doSomething()
    {
        //Is there a way here to call A(the Creator) method resetValues();
        //Like Creator.resetValues();
    }
}
```

So is there a way to call the Creator methods like in this Example Class A method's .
This is is very needful when i use a Form to show Another Form :
from FormA

```
FormB frmB = new FormB();
frmB.Show();
this.hide();
```

Than i should `onFormClose` Event of FormB to Show again the FormA

**EDIT**
First i thought parsing A by Ref as Object ,but Storing a Reference as a Field later i founded out that's impossible !

First i thought maybe using reflection we can Identify and Call Creator method's but i think i mismatched some of **OOP Design Pattern's**

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but probably better pattern to follow: events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is to pass in the "creator" when calling the constructor:

```
 B b = new B(this);
```

Of course, that means that `B` needs to have a constructor with the appropriate parameter type, which should match whatever it needs to do with its creator.

EDIT: As noted in comments, it doesn't really need to be done *at construction* - it could be a property:

```
 B b = new B();
 b.Creator = this;
```

They amount to basically the same thing though.

I would suggest this is *usually* a bad idea, to be honest. It's introducing a reasonably tight coupling between the two classes. It might be better for `B` to publish an event which the creator can subscribe to, in order to handle appropriate state changes etc on `B`.

Comment: What about property injection? I know it isn't nice either, but it is another option.

Comment: @Oded: You mean setting `b.Creator = this;` afterwards? Yes, that's a possibility - much the same thing, really. Will edit.

Comment: +1 for using an event to notify instead of tightly coupling the two classes. OP seems to be at a good stage to start learning about events.

Comment: @Jon Skeet by sending this i`ll Lose Changed into class A ,because i think using b.Creator = this; is Pass by Value ,or it's not i still can see changes at A even if i do that .

Comment: @Cody: It would pass the *reference* by value. It feels to me like if you're concerned by this sort of thing you should revise the fundamental bits of C# to start with - have a look at http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply `Action` instead `Func<bool>`, returning bool allows passing back a state which indicating whether operation was executed successfully.

```
class B
{ 
  private Func<bool> executeExternal;

  public B(Func<bool> executeExternal) 
  {
       this.executeExternal= executeExternal;

       // here is resetValues() will be executed in case of B class
       bool isDoneSuccessfully = this.executeExternal();
  } 
}

public class A 
{     
  public void resetValues()     
  {         
     //DoSomething     
  }      

  // basically we injecting a delegate
  B b = new B(() => { this.resetValues(); return true; } ); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on from [@Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528031/how-to-call-creator-methods/7528052#7528052), it would be preferable for class B to emit an event when something happens and for class A to consume that event.

In this way, class B has no dependency on class A. You could reuse class B with classes other than class A without modifying the internals of class B. From a maintenance POV, this is far more preferable.

You could set it up as follows:

```
public class A
{
    B b = new B();

    public A()
    {
       b.SomethingHappened += SomethingHappenedHandler; 
    }
    public void resetValues()
    {
        //DoSomething
    }
    public void SomethingHappenedHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        resetValues();
    }

}
```

and

```
public class B
{
    public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;
    public B()
    {

    }

    void doSomething()
    {
        var ev = SomethingHappened;
        if(ev != null)
        {
            ev(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```